# Reservation "under the name", "in the name", or "by the name" of Ms. X

Tags: idioms, prepositions, word-usage

Which idiom of "by the name", "under the name", and "in the name" is appropriate for reservations?

e.g.

*There's a reservation [**by the name of** Cullen](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/3870116/35/Meyer-University)*...

*She made the reservation [**in the name of** Jordan Sinclair](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=YUsiaYPFcgsC&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230&dq=%22reservation%20in%20the%20name%20of%22&source=bl&ots=C3yXbzoa2Z&sig=W5Crvr2PaErGcKrKlUwvscFpxio&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=dEv9Uu2XG-rH7AaYmICgDA&ved=0CCcQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22reservation%20in%20the%20name%20of%22&f=false)*...

*Make your reservation [**under the name of** ECW](http://ecw.dioala.org/Fall%20Conference/fall-conference-registration.html)*...

Instinctively, I would go for "under", but I'm just not positively sure.

If all three options actually work, is any of them more typical of a variety of English than another, or they all can be used just about interchangeably in all varieties?

Comment: When you say "English" dialect, do you mean British English?

Comment: @KristinaLopez I mean more typical to an English variety than to another. ;)

Comment: [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reservation+by+the+name%2Creservation+in+the+name%2Creservation+under+the+name&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creservation%20in%20the%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creservation%20under%20the%20name%3B%2Cc0) may be enlightening. Essentially, ***in*** is more common than ***under***, particularly in recent decades. And ***by*** has always been so uncommon it's below the radar.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How would a BrEng speaker normally say that he/she has made a reservation? Would "I have a reservation for (surname/lastname)" be used? I don't think I have ever made a reservation for a table in the UK; it's always been done by someone else!

Comment: @Mari-Lou: Well, as joseph_morris rightly points out in his answer, you wouldn't normally say *the name of* anyway (if you *did*, it would suggest that's *not* your real name). Contrary to my NGram link, I too would tend to say ***under*** if I had to choose between that and ***in***. But in practice when I walk in I normally say *"You should have a reservation **for** Smith"* (though actually that's not my real name, and I can honestly say that in all my "dirty weekends away" I've *never* registered under a false name! :)

Comment: You forgot "for". Someone made a reservation for "Rockefeller", party of 42. Most likely someone named "Joe" -- he keeps doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For AE (midwest, Calif.), I recognize all three as acceptable, but would tend to use "under". It's what I encounter most frequently, but I'm also imagining the host looking up the reservation name in a book with a bunch of tabs with letters on them (even though that's not actually what's happening most of the time). You can also just say "I have a reservation under Franklin".

If I were actually showing up at a restaurant, I'd most frequently use "for" -- "Hi, we have a reservation for Franklin."

"In the name of" has a slight implication that you're making the reservation with a name other than your own.

Answer (score 5):

I do think there is a difference between **'in the name'** and **'under the name'**. For instance, the secretary calls the hotel and asks *to make a reservation in the name of her boss Mr.Cullen*.  On the other hand, let's imagine I go to the conference and ***I make my reservation or get registered under the name of my company MTC***. That's how I see it.